# Null values in python from CSV reports

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a problem with importing CSV file into python.
Whole file in .csv format has normal values in all cells, but during the process of copying data to data frame there is an error and some Null Values are poping up, which makes impossible to make this operation.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_path
df=pd.read_csv(excel_path, error_bad_lines=False, sep=';',dtype='c')
print (df)
```

I've also tried with other way of working but with the same result.

```
import csv

excel_path
with open(excel_path, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

Do you know any way how to change a way of loading data into python? I have checked already existing topics and tried with different coding. In my file CSV file are numbers, strings and dates.

There is no error with Null values. The problem is that those values appears. In CSV file there are normal strings and integers. I need this data, that is why I cannot just pass null values.

This is how this file looks as data frame:

```
     R  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  
0    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
2    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
3    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
4    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
...   ..         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
1326 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1327 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1328 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1329 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1330 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

When I will add 'dtype = 'c' to this code line:
df=pd.read_csv(excel_path, error_bad_lines=False)
I receiv something like this:

```
   R Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6  \
0     b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
1     b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
2     b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
3     b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
4     b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
...   ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...   
1326  b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
1327  b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
1328  b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
1329  b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''   
1330  b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''        b''
```

My CSV file looks like this:

```
RNSP_ID;AUTHOR ID;PRODUCT FAMILY;REQUEST SCOPE;HC Prog;DRAWING NUMBER;VALIDITY;PART TYPE;DOCUMENT OF DEFINITION;CLASSIFICATION;ENGLISH DESIGNATION;FRENCH DESIGNATION;CREATION DATE;
RNSP11701;G700895;Fasteners;Selection;H60;U533A;Serial;Normalised;AS3510;4.7.6;"CABLE SAFETY KIT;"CABLE DE SECURITE;"SICHERUNGSDRAHTKIT;"CABLE SAFETY KIT;17/03/2015 13:38:23;
RNSP11701;G700895;Fasteners;Selection;H60;U533A;Serial;Normalised;AS3510;4.7.6;"CABLE SAFETY KIT;"CABLE DE SECURITE;"SICHERUNGSDRAHTKIT;"CABLE SAFETY KIT;17/03/2015 13:38:23;
RNSP11707;xa434956;Fasteners;Creation;H60;U311A;Serial;Normalised;NSA 551.33;4.8.1;"STUD;"FERMETURE RAPIDE;"VERSCHLUSSZAPFEN;"PASADOR DE CIERRE;19/03/2015 09:28:18;
RNSP11746;xa444992;Fasteners;Use of a new;H60;U...;Serial;Non Aero;ISO7070;4.7.1.1;"NUT HEXA;"ECROU;"NUSS;"NUT;27/03/2015 12:47:53;
RNSP11746;xa444992;Fasteners;Use of a new;H60;U...;Serial;Non Aero;ISO7071;4.7.1.1;"NUT HEXA;"ECROU;"NUSS;"NUT;27/03/2015 12:47:53;
RNSP11747;xa444992;Fasteners;Addition;H60;U...;Serial;Non Aero;DIN950;4.7.1.1;"HANDWHEELS;"VOLANTS;"HANDRADER;"HANDWHEELS;27/03/2015 13:19:24;
RNSP11749;xa444992;Fasteners;Addition;H60;U...;Serial;Non Aero;DIN934;4.2.1.1;"HEXAGONAL NUT;"HEXAGONAL NUT;"SECHSKANTMUTTER;"HEXAGONAL NUT;27/03/2015 13:48:24;
RNSP11749;xa444992;Fasteners;Addition;H60;U...;Serial;Non Aero;DIN934;4.2.1.1;"HEXAGONAL NUT;"HEXAGONAL NUT;"SECHSKANTMUTTER;"HEXAGONAL NUT;27/03/2015 13:48:24;
RNSP11750;xa444992;Fasteners;Addition;H10;U...;Serial;Non Aero;ISO7089;4.3.1;"WASHER, FLAT;"RONDELLE;"SCHEIBE, FLACH;"WASHER, FLAT;27/03/2015 14:01:53;
RNSP11750;xa444992;Fasteners;Addition;H10;U...;Serial;Non Aero;ISO7089;4.3.1;"WASHER, FLAT;"RONDELLE;"SCHEIBE, FLACH;"WASHER, FLAT;27/03/2015 14:01:53;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: if the null values are causing the error try using the `.notna()` command?

Comment: I don't fully understand you. The amount of columns is correct. There should not be some other at the end. CREATION DATE is ending with ;
But the issue remains. Pandas cannot read this data, and gives only NaN values.

Comment: _CREATION DATE is ending with ;_ - only after you edited it. Other than that, based on the sample shown, the data imports correctly. However, that doesn't mean there aren't other issues with the file.

Comment: Yes, I have added manualy ; at the end. It just didn't copied from the file. Sorry for that.
But what does it mean? What could be changed in original CSV file to make it possible to read values?

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSV file has two problems:

1. The number of columns is different from the number of headers, as @TrentonMcKinney pointed out, by two, and
2. It has some random `"` (single 'double quotes') that make pandas parser freak out

I was able to correctly parse it by removing all `"` in the file and then apply the following command to import it:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('20210108.csv',skiprows=[0],names=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],delimiter=';', index_col=False)
```

In detail:

- the CSV file has been ridden of the `"`s
- delimiter is set to `;`
- I asked panda to skip the first row (headers that are not aligned) and gave columns number headers from 1 to 15 (one header missing was obvious and it's a language, something like '<german?> DESIGNATION' the other was not so I replaced them with numbers)
- I also forced pandas to import without an index column because the first one didn't look like one.

Now the data frame seems reasonable:

```
>>> df
          1         2          3             4    5      6       7   \
0  RNSP11701   G700895  Fasteners     Selection  H60  U533A  Serial   
1  RNSP11701   G700895  Fasteners     Selection  H60  U533A  Serial   
2  RNSP11707  xa434956  Fasteners      Creation  H60  U311A  Serial   
3  RNSP11746  xa444992  Fasteners  Use of a new  H60   U...  Serial   
4  RNSP11746  xa444992  Fasteners  Use of a new  H60   U...  Serial   
5  RNSP11747  xa444992  Fasteners      Addition  H60   U...  Serial   
6  RNSP11749  xa444992  Fasteners      Addition  H60   U...  Serial   
7  RNSP11749  xa444992  Fasteners      Addition  H60   U...  Serial   
8  RNSP11750  xa444992  Fasteners      Addition  H10   U...  Serial   
9  RNSP11750  xa444992  Fasteners      Addition  H10   U...  Serial   

           8           9        10                11                 12  \
0  Normalised      AS3510    4.7.6  CABLE SAFETY KIT  CABLE DE SECURITE   
1  Normalised      AS3510    4.7.6  CABLE SAFETY KIT  CABLE DE SECURITE   
2  Normalised  NSA 551.33    4.8.1              STUD   FERMETURE RAPIDE   
3    Non Aero     ISO7070  4.7.1.1          NUT HEXA              ECROU   
4    Non Aero     ISO7071  4.7.1.1          NUT HEXA              ECROU   
5    Non Aero      DIN950  4.7.1.1        HANDWHEELS            VOLANTS   
6    Non Aero      DIN934  4.2.1.1     HEXAGONAL NUT      HEXAGONAL NUT   
7    Non Aero      DIN934  4.2.1.1     HEXAGONAL NUT      HEXAGONAL NUT   
8    Non Aero     ISO7089    4.3.1      WASHER, FLAT           RONDELLE   
9    Non Aero     ISO7089    4.3.1      WASHER, FLAT           RONDELLE   

                   13                 14                   15  
0  SICHERUNGSDRAHTKIT   CABLE SAFETY KIT  17/03/2015 13:38:23  
1  SICHERUNGSDRAHTKIT   CABLE SAFETY KIT  17/03/2015 13:38:23  
2    VERSCHLUSSZAPFEN  PASADOR DE CIERRE  19/03/2015 09:28:18  
3                NUSS                NUT  27/03/2015 12:47:53  
4                NUSS                NUT  27/03/2015 12:47:53  
5           HANDRADER         HANDWHEELS  27/03/2015 13:19:24  
6     SECHSKANTMUTTER      HEXAGONAL NUT  27/03/2015 13:48:24  
7     SECHSKANTMUTTER      HEXAGONAL NUT  27/03/2015 13:48:24  
8      SCHEIBE, FLACH       WASHER, FLAT  27/03/2015 14:01:53  
9      SCHEIBE, FLACH       WASHER, FLAT  27/03/2015 14:01:53
```